# Problema relacionado con substring JAVA

Tags: java

A ver, tengo un problema con un ejercicio de Strings que estoy haciendo. Tengo que mostrar en pantalla una fecha tipo dd/mm/aaaa y me tiene que devolver los días los meses y los años por separado. Ese no es el problema porque entiendo como hacer el substring y eso. El problema está cuando pongo un espacio a la respuesta y me da este error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   begin 0, end 2, length 1 at
>   java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3720) at
>   java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1909) at
>   ex5.main(ex5.java:17)

```
import cs1.*;
public class ex5
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    String data = "18/08/2011";



    //asking for the data
    System.out.printf("DATA: ");
    data = Keyboard.readString();



    //system.out
    System.out.printf("DIA: %s %n", data.substring(0, 2));
    System.out.printf("MES: %s %n", data.substring(3, 5));
    System.out.printf("ANY: %s", data.substring(6, 10)); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la cadena es más corta del tamaño que intentas recortar, el método substring lanza una excepción, para evitarlo puedes comprobar el tamaño de la cadena antes, por ejemplo así:

```
if(data.length()<10){
    System.out.print("Tamaño de cadena menor a 10");
}else{
    System.out.printf("DIA: %s %n", data.substring(0, 2));
    System.out.printf("MES: %s %n", data.substring(3, 5));
    System.out.printf("ANY: %s", data.substring(6, 10)); 
}
```

Comment: gracias! me has ayudado muchisimo era algo realmente muy simple pero gracias!

Comment: @SebastiánMoreno Si esta respuesta te ayudó, debes de marcarla como aceptada, con el símbolo check (✓) que está al costado izquierdo de la respuesta :)

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo puede solucionar cambiando la última linea de impresión

```
System.out.printf("ANY: %s", data.substring(6));
```

De está forma no require indicar la longitud del `substring`.

Si no es obligatorio el subString se puede usar el método `split`, si la fecha siempre llega en el mismo formato `dd/mm/aaaa` entones se puede hacer

```
String[] fechaSeparada = data.split("/");
System.out.printf("DIA: %s %n", fehaSeparada[0]);
System.out.printf("MES: %s %n", fehaSeparada[1]);
System.out.printf("ANY: %s", fehaSeparada[2]);
```